# Unable to SSH Using a Private Key Through Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, permissions

To start with, I apologize if this is a painfully obvious/trivial issue, I'm still learning the ins and outs of linux/unix.

I work with a few servers that require access via ssh and private key to log into. So, the command is something like this:

`ssh -i /path/to/key.pem user@000.000.000.000`

I've created a bash script that let's me just use my own call, `access`, and just has a basic switch statement for the arguments that follow to control which server I log into. For example, `access server1` would issue the appropriate `ssh` command to log into server1.

**The Problem**

The `ssh` call just hangs up and I'm left with an empty terminal that won't accept `SIGINT` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) and I must quit the terminal and open it up again to even use it.

As far as I can tell, this might be a permissions thing for the private key. Its permissions are currently `600`. Changing it to `644` gives me an error that the permissions are too open and exits the `ssh` attempt. Any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. There is `ssh_config`, made for this, where you can specify your hosts aliases and keys and store it without creating such hara-kiri as bash scripts to do so. It is basically stored in your `~/.ssh/config` in this format:

   ```
   Host host1
     Hostname 000.000.000.000
     User user
     IdentityFile /path/to/key.pem
   ```

   and then you can simply call

   ```
   ssh host1
   ```

   to get to `000.000.000.000`
2. If you really want to be *effective* and have even shorter shortcuts, bash `alias` is more suitable than the bash scripts.

   ```
   alias access="ssh -i /path/to/key.pem user@000.000.000.000"
   ```
3. If you really want to use bash script, you need to force ssh to allocate you TTY on remote server using `-tt` option:

   ```
   ssh -tti /path/to/key.pem user@000.000.000.000
   ```

For more tips, you can browse through the manual page for `ssh` and `ssh_config`.

Comment: Well, if I didn't feel like I already knew too little about linux, I certainly feel that even more now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I generally make password auth available on servers (via console, assuming you are using virtualization), then `ssh-copy-id soandso@server` to get a key-based authentication going. Do note that in most cases you are using a public key (on your machine) to authenticate against a private key (on remote server).

The pub key standard permissions should be `644`, however your private key should be `700` to the best of my knowledge. Are you sure your issue isn't the pub key permissions?

I would recommend checking two things: first, try the ssh connection string you did above, and add -v or -vvv as your option. This should give you a good idea where this is breaking at. Second, take a look at the sshd config file (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) on the server and make sure the connection protocol you are attempting to use is enabled. This could be as simple as making sure theses two lines are set to yes:

`RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes`

Best of luck!